# Free SSL VPN client

Tags: windows, vpn, ssl, 64-bit, x86

What is the best free SSL VPN client that works on 64 and 32 bit windows clients?

Comment: When you say SSL VPN, do you mean a VPN that uses SSL or an SSL gateway that acts like a VPN?

Comment: I'm really looking for something that I can use to replace the Forticlient SSL VPN software, but also want something that can be used to access other networks.
I assume this is a VPN that uses SSL.

Comment: Yes. This is a VPN that uses SSL to negotiate the connection securely.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try OpenVPN (http://openvpn.net/). It's cross-platform, completely free, extremely secure, and once configured it's extremely easy to deploy. I can't confirm whether it specifically targets x64, but the x86 build should work on the x64 architecture.

Edit: I should mention that OpenVPN won a "Bossie" in 2007 as the [best Open Source VPN](http://www.infoworld.com/%5Bprimary-term-alias-prefix%5D/%5Bprimary-term%5D/best-open-source-in-security-835&current=8&last=1#slideshowTop).

Also, OpenVPN 2.1 is Vista-ready on both x86 and x64.

Comment: OpenVPN (http://openvpn.net) is only able to connect to their own service - which they call "**Shield Exchange**".

Answer (score 0):

You could use Windows 2008 Server and the built-in [Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.cableguy.aspx)?  You could use the built-in Windows Vista/7 networking client and the configuration is very simple.

Comment: Just re-read the question and missed the "free" requirement.  Sorry about that...